# Hide Row(Multiple Row) After Clicked in TableView

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5, ios4, ios6

I Am developing one Application. This  Application Contain TableView If i once click any one row that row i  want to hide after some operation, Can Any one help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suggestion for you:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray   *tableItems;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger         hideIndex;
```

Add UITableView delegate methods and in didSelectRowAtIndex method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Store index of row to hide.
self.hideIndex = indexPath.row;   
}
```

Create your operation method

```
- (void) doOperation {

// Remove index from table datasource.
@try {
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tableItems];
    [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:self.hideIndex];

    self.tableItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
    tempArray = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Handle exception");
}
}
```

So that on next reload of UITableView will show remaining cells. And remove your selected cell.